# Right-click handler for dynamically created buttons

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I created 81 Buttons dynamically and I can detect a normal `Click` on any of these buttons, but I'm not sure how to detect a right-click. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnArray_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim itemClicked As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Dim index As Integer = -1

    For i As Integer = LBound(btnArray) To UBound(btnArray)
        If btnArray(i) Is itemClicked Then
            index = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If index > 0 Then 
        'MessageBox.Show("Sie haben den Button Nr. " & CStr(index) & " angeklickt")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You can replace your entire `For` loop with `Array.IndexOf(btnArray, itemClicked)`

Comment: Also, in your question, it isn't super clear what you are asking about.  If you are asking about detecting right-click, use `MouseDown` instead of `Click`, it will give you an `EventArgs` that has the mouse buttons in it.

Comment: @PowerBauer, I've slightly reworded your question to make it clearer. If I've misunderstood what you are asking, please feel free to rollback my edit. (I've also assumed this question is about WinForms...).

I guess you're adding `btnArray_Click` as the handler for the `Click` event when you're dynamically creating all the buttons in `btnArray`?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the timing that you want to handle (when the user clicks the button or when the user releases the click), you can either handle the `MouseDown` or `MouseUp` event. Both of them have event args of type [`MouseEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs) that tell you which mouse button was clicked.

```
Private Sub btnArray_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        MessageBox.Show("You have right-clicked a button")
    End If
End Sub
```